# Graphical user interface for 4-dimensional visualisation

Tags: geometry, reference-request, differential-topology

Does anyone know a research / programming literature that explores *computer-graphics* visualisation of 4-dimensional geometry? Here is a simple method that I was considering to implement by myself. I suspect that this was tried before, so I wanted to know if anyone saw this implemented or explored before.

Given a compact set $M \subset \mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ and a pair of vectors $v = (v_{\text{pos}}, v_{\text{view}}) \in \mathbb{R}^{d+1} \times \mathbb{S}^d$, let $\pi_v \subset \mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ be the affine $d$-dimensional plane that passes through $v_{\text{pos}}$ and is orthogonal to $v_{\text{view}}$. Then we may define $M_v \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ to be the orthogonal projection of $M$ onto $\pi_v \simeq \mathbb{R}^d$. For $d=2$, this is the familiar way in which 2-dimensional shadows are produced. For $d=3$, we get 3-dimensional objects $M_v \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ that are shadows of the 4-dimensional object $M$.

My goal is to design a **computer graphical interface** that allows intuitive exploration of these objects $M_v$. In the methods described above, this means designing a computer interface that allows users to easily explore the viewing parameter space $v = (v_{\text{pos}}, v_{\text{view}}) \in \mathbb{R}^{4} \times \mathbb{S}^3$. Ignoring $\mathbb{R}^4$ for the moment, there is a rich variety of choices to make a user interface to move on the 3-sphere $\mathbb{S}^3$.

- $\mathbb{S}^3$ is the quotient space obtained by identifying all boundary points of the *solid* 3-dimensional ball. This way, the 4-dimensional viewing angles can be visualised by exploring a 3-dimensional ball, which is intuitive to humans.
- $\mathbb{S}^3$ is the double cover of the $SO(3)$, so that an interface for exploring the 3-dimensional rotations can be used to explore $\mathbb{S}^3$. Doing this would require lifting a path on $SO(3)$ to a path on $\mathbb{S}^3$.
- $\mathbb{S}^3$ is a $\mathbb{S}^1$-bundle over $\mathbb{S}^2$; this is the Hopf fibration $\mathbb{S}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$. Equipped with  a way to lift a path in $\mathbb{S}^2$ to a path in $\mathbb{S}^3$, a user would be able to separately control the $\mathbb{S}^2$-part and the $\mathbb{S}^1$-part of the $\mathbb{S}^3$.

Comment: This is a great question, though maybe not ideally suited for MSE? <> Whether or no, there's a Discord channel on illustrating mathematics that you might investigate. Particularly, Hamish Todd has a [video](https://youtu.be/g5XWNwBJWeY) _What does it look like to rotate things in 4 dimensions?_ that uses VR for purposes that sound similar to your question. Work by Tom Banchoff and collaborators would also be a good place to search for leads.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to ask this here first because it would take me some work to translate my thoughts that are easier to parse for computer engineers. Could you tell me how to look for that Discord server?

Comment: Are you planning a 3D or 2D graphics?

Comment: I think it makes sense to first make a 3D graphics, and examine it using 2D projections (just as how 3D graphics usually work)